# Powershell Select-String how to filter by date?

Tags: powershell

I have a log file that starts with date format, I want to filter out lines that were added in the past 5min and work on them, but when I run my code it gives me wrong data

**Log file Syntax**

```
01/12/2020 00:00:00 log info
```

**Code**

```
$referenceTime = '{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
Get-Content -Path 'C:\..\data.log' |
Where-Object { (($_ -split '\s')[0] + " " + ($_ -split '\s')[1]) -gt $referenceTime } |
ForEach-Object {
    #DO SOMETHING..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates should be compared to other dates, so you should not stringify them.

Try

```
$referenceTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)
Get-Content -Path 'C:\..\data.log' |
Where-Object { $_ -match '^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})' } |
Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null) -gt $referenceTime } |
ForEach-Object {
    $_
    #DO SOMETHING.. For demo just output the line(s) that matched
}
```

The first `Where-Object` matches any line that starts with what looks like a date in the given format and captures that part of the line in `$matches[1]`.
The second `Where-Object` parses this matched date into a real `[DateTime]` object, so you can compare it with the date in `$referenceTime`

Comment: It returns dates smaller then $referenceTime, for example
$referenceTime = 02/03/2021 15:59:29

Script retuns line
10/11/2020 04:31:23 data...

Comment: @BugsBunny Ah, sorry, forgot to paste the important bit where it parses `$matches[1]` into a datetime object. Fixed now